# nginx as a web proxy with ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have installed proxmox and am running a simple ubuntu server where I have installed nginx. How and where do I setup ssl? I only want to use nginx to forward location to another web server. Can I set up Let's Encrypt ssl on the nginx server and forward to port 80 on the other web server or do I have to set up ssl on each of the targets?

I will have many dns names passing through the nginx proxy

Comment: set SSL up on nginx

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can setup Let's Encrypt ssl on the nginx server and forward to port 80 of other web server.

You may find the answer/discussion on this similar post helpful, [nginx as reverse proxy with several domains hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/938419/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-several-domains-hosts?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt creates temporary files inside **.well-known** directory for authentication. This doesn't work when you're using nginx as a proxy. I think easiest thing you can do is to rewrite **.well-known** to a local, accessible location.

I'm adaption these instructions from [Setup Let’s Encrypt with Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://vpsfix.com/15917/setup-letsencrypt-with-nginx-reverse-proxy/).

Open nginx config file for the domain,

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com.conf
```

Paste following code before proxy settings,

```
location /.well-known {
        alias /var/www/something/html/.well-known;
}
```

Restart nginx

```
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Try it!